# How to hide the labels of \email and \telephone

Tags: letters, email, lettre

I'm currently writing letters with LaTeX and the corresponding class. I'm writing my contact informations on a different file to use with \institute, and I can't find how to hide the "e-mail:" and the "phone:" labels. People know how what an email address look like, as long as a phone number, it takes space for nothing. I looked for it here and on other websites, I can't find anything...

Thank you if you have any idea to help !

[image: The Institute section with these labels]

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,origdate]{lettre}%
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mltex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\institut{identite}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Mme Prénom \textsc{Nom} \\
Fonction}

\conc{Objet de la lettre}
\opening{Madame,}

\lipsum[1]

\closing{Formule de politesse,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

identite.ins:

```
%-% Pour supprimer le trait de pliure
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NoRule}{\renewcommand*{\rule@length}{0}}
\makeatother

\NoRule
\name{Prénom \textsc{Nom}}
\address{\centering
Prénom \textsc{Nom} \\
42, avenue de la Bioinfo \\
42~314 \textsc{Bioinfo-fr}}
\telephone{06~07~08~09~10}
%-% C'est \fax{} pour indiquer un numéro de fax ;)
\nofax
\lieu{\textsc{Limoges}}
\date{le \today}
\signature{Prénom \textsc{Nom}}
\email{login@ndd.tld}
```

Comment: show a small but *complete*  example that can be used for test. I have not the faintest idea which class and commands you actually use (there are various letter classes around).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the corresponding commands `\tellabelname` and `\emaillabelname` from the `\letteropening` macro (which generates the header). To remove the commands you can use the `etoolbox` package, which is already loaded by the `lettre` class. This package provides the `\patchcmd` macro that performs a find and replace substitution in the code of the command that is being patched. In this case you want to replace both commands with nothing. There are 5 arguments to `\patchcmd`: the command being patched, the search string, the replace string, and two arguments that are executed when the patching is succesful or not, respectively (these final two arguments can be left empty).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,origdate]{lettre}%
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\institut{identite}
\begin{document}
\patchcmd{\letteropening}{\emaillabelname}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\letteropening}{\tellabelname}{}{}{}
\begin{letter}{Mme Prénom \textsc{Nom} \\
Fonction}
\conc{Objet de la lettre}
\opening{Madame,}

\lipsum[1]

\closing{Formule de politesse,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To find the relevant macros for patching I searched the source code of the `lettre` class for the string 'email' which lead me to `\emaillabelname`. That in turn resulted in finding the macro `\letteropening`.